# How to retry fetch email with IMAP nodejs and cypres

Tags: node.js, cypress, imap

I want to use imap nodejs library to fetch email in my cypress tests. Everything works fine if email is found. However, if mail is not found, it throws exception. I would like to try to give some time while e-mail is recieved, so would like to retry fetching 50-100 times. Any idea how to do it?

This is my imap code in cypress config file

```
   const myTask = {

    ...          

    imap.once('ready', function() {
              openInbox(function (err, box) {
                if (err) throw err;
                imap.search(filter, function (err, results) {
                  if (err) throw err;
                  var f = imap.fetch(results, { bodies: '1', markSeen: true });
                  f.on('message', function (msg, seqno) {
                    console.log('Message #%d' + seqno);
                    console.log('Message type' + msg.text)
                    var prefix = '(#' + seqno + ') ';
                    msg.on('body', function (stream, info) {
                      var buffer = '', count = 0;
                      stream.on('data', function (chunk) {
                        buffer += chunk.toString('utf8');
                        console.log("BUFFER" + buffer)
                      })
                      stream.once('end', function () {
                        if (info.which === '1') {
                          console.log("BUFFER" + buffer)
                        }
                      });
                      console.log(prefix + 'Body');
                      stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('msg-' + seqno + '-body.txt'));
                    });
                    msg.once('attributes', function (attrs) {
                      console.log(prefix + 'Attributes: %s', inspect(attrs, false, 8));
                    });
                    msg.once('end', function () {
                      console.log(prefix + 'Finished');
                    });
                  });
                  f.once('error', function (err) {
                    console.log('Fetch error: ' + err);
                  });
                  f.once('end', function () {
                    console.log('Done fetching all messages!');
                    imap.end();
                  });
                });
              });
            });
```

}
...

and from command file I call this function

```
Cypress.Commands.add('fechEmail', () => {
return cy.task('fetchEmail', ['UNSEEN', ['SUBJECT', 'stone']]).then(res => {
  return res
})
```

})

Answer (score 0):

It throws the error in the test because in the task `if (err) throw err;`. Any error thrown in the task fails the test that calls the task, so don't throw an error there if you want to try again a bit later.

Instead of that use `if (err) return null;`

Then in the test, handle the null value to retry, something like

```js
cy.fetchEmail().then(res => {
  if (res === null) {
    cy.wait(5_000)
    cy.fetchEmail().then(res => {
      ...
```

Comment: Thanks Ricky. I replaced both lines 'if (err) throw err;' with 'if (err) return null' and I got same error as before"Nothing to fetch'. I think your code just retries once after 5 seconds. What If I want to retry every 5 seconds for 3 minutes and break if email is fetched?

Comment: Ok, maybe it's the format of the task - not unwrapping that array you sent through properly.